# Polymer - Change page title with iron-pages

Tags: polymer, web-component, polymer-1.0

Lets say I have the demo implementation of `iron-pages` (from its [Github page](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-pages)):

```
<iron-pages selected="0">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
</iron-pages>

<script>
  document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var pages = document.querySelector('iron-pages');
    pages.selectNext();
  });
</script>
```

Now, I want to add a suffix to the page title to reflect the selected page. So for `<div>One</div>` I would like to append `- selected One` and so on.

**What I've got so far** is to make the change in `routing.html` when the route has been selected but it seems a bit weird to make the change here. Are there any other ways of doing this?

Comment: Should clarify that this is using the Polymer Starter Kit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should take a look at my Polymer component `<page-title>` here: https://github.com/zacharytamas/page-title/. You can install it with Bower, too:

```
bower install page-title --save
```

Likely you'd want some kind of function that maps the selected index from `<iron-pages>` to text you want to show as the title. In your example you could just the `innerText` of the selected element, but in practice your `<iron-pages>` elements would actually have content in them.

This will depend on your setup but you could use my component to easily bind them, something like this:

```
<dom-module id="my-app">
  <template>

    <page-title base-title="My Website" 
      title="[[selectedPage.title]]"></page-title>

    <iron-pages selected-item="{{selectedPage}}">
      <div title="First Page">One</div>
      <div title="Second Page">Two</div>
      <div title="Third Page">Three</div>
    </iron-pages>

  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-app'
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Here I've just done some fanciness to bind the title of the page to the `title` attribute of the currently selected element from the `<iron-pages>`. It works pretty well! You may have to adopt to your situation but this should get you going.

Comment: Do you have a page with an example where you bind the attrs? Or an example?

Answer (score 0):

The value of your title element can be a computed property based on the value of {{selected}}, i.e:

```
<myTitle text={{title}} currentSelection={{selected}}></myTitle>
```

//declarative portion of element

```
<dom-module id="myTitle">
<template>
    <div>{{title}}</div>
</template>
</dom-module>
```

//imperative portion

```
Polymer({

is: 'myTitle',

properties: {
    title: {
        type: String,
        computed: 'generateTitle'
    },

    currentSelection: {
        type: Number
    }
},

'generateTitle': function(){
    return '- selected' + this.currentSelection;
}

});
```

Comment: I get this concept but what about using the existing `<title>` tag?

Comment: I think Polymer 1.0 allows you to extend native HTML elements, so you could use the `<title>` tag as your base and add functionality from there: [link](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html#type-extension)